# ios project in flutter not show push notification

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I send a push notification from Firebase. I do not receive it on the real device and the Apple emulator. If i don't get any error and i also get device token.
In xcode, I have activated push notifications and background modes.
The value of FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled has been set to 0.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
  };
  PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
    return true;
  };
  NotificationApi.init();
  notificationHandler();
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();
  late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging;
  _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  NotificationSettings settings = await _messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage event) {
    print("message recieved");
    print(event.notification!.body);
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
    print('Message clicked!');
  });
  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    print('User granted permission');
    // TODO: handle the received notifications
  } else {
    print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
  }
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging =
      FirebaseMessaging.instance; // Change here
  _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
    print("token is $token");
  });
```

```
class NotificationApi {
  static final _notification = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void init() {
    _notification.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
        iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
      ),
    );
  }

  static scheduleNotification() async {
    timezone.initializeTimeZones();
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel id',
      'channel name',
      channelDescription: 'channel description',
      importance: Importance.max, // set the importance of the notification
      priority: Priority.high, // set prority
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = const DarwinNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    await _notification.zonedSchedule(
        1,
        "notification title",
        'Message goes here',
        timezone.TZDateTime.now(timezone.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 10)),
        platformChannelSpecifics,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
  }

  static pushNotification(
      RemoteMessage message,
      ) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channed id',
      'channel name',
      channelDescription: 'channel description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = const DarwinNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    await _notification.show(
        1,
        message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body,
        platformChannelSpecifics);

  }
}
```

[image]

The interesting thing is that I receive the device token, but I do not receive the push notification on the device. How can I print the sent notification in the console to make sure everything is correct, so that I can find out where the problem is?

```
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage event) {
    print("message recieved");
    print(event.notification!.body);
  });
```

This command is not executed !!!! No error and also nothing is printed in the console !!!